# How to convert [45,32,56] or "45,32,56" to 42,32,56?

Tags: arrays, ruby, splat

I have a hash from which I want to get specific keys

```
a={1=>32, 23=>23, 24=>232, 56=>123} 
keys=[23,56]
```

To get values of this keys from a{}, I'm using function

```
a.values_at 23,56 # => [23, 232]`
```

Problem is how do I convert `[23,56....]` to `23,56`

Comment: You may use it as num1, num2 = [23, 232]

Comment: Hey,Thanks for your answer but what if there would have been 100 values in an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use splat operator (`*` before the argument) to [convert array to arguments](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion):

```
a={1=>32, 23=>23, 24=>232, 56=>123} 
# => {1=>32, 23=>23, 24=>232, 56=>123}
keys=[23,56]
# => [23, 56]
a.values_at(*keys)
#=> [23, 123]
```

See also:

- https://medium.com/@sologoubalex/parameter-with-splat-operator-in-ruby-part-1-2-a1c2176215a5

Comment: Hey mrzasa,Thanks a lot,
Today came to knew *(splat) best use case.